# Location of Gnome Classic (metacity) quicklaunch shortcuts?

Tags: gnome-classic

What is the directory that .desktop files are copied to when a .desktop file is dragged to the Gnome Clasic quicklaunch bar? I would like to be able to modify them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answers!

The configuration is at: `org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout`.

The objects are at: `org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout.objects`.

When dragged to the gnome-panel, the original dragged desktop is specified in the configuration.

Execute: `killall gnome-panel` to propagate changes to said `.desktop` files.

Answer (score 1):

A normal user cannot modify the system-wide .desktop files at /usr/share/applications/ because they are read only, so a copy is made whenever you modify any shortcut, whether it is on the menu or on the panel.

All the user's modified .desktop files are stored in ~/.local/share/applications/. If you make new shortcuts they are also stored here.